# How to integrate wordpress in my Android app

Tags: android, wordpress, xml-rpc

I want to build an application in which user can Log in with his Wordpress account, then he can also create, edit, see different posts present in his account. I have gone through so many links but still unable to understand how can I do this.

Finally I got a name called "XML-RPC API". But I am not aware of anything regarding the same. My app flow should be like that :-

Step1 - User should be able to login to his wordpress account.

Step2 - User can Create a new Post.

Step3 - User will be able to see all of the posts previously created and also can    edit it.

I am struggling with the same, any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have heard of XML-RPC for the first time, belive me you dont want to go that way :P. Unless you have lot of spare time and someone who is pretty good with API's.

I dont know if you have heard about it, but there are many services that offer you to create your own android and ios app. There is even a free plugin for it
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wiziapp-create-your-own-native-iphone-app/

And then there is an app from wordpress it self, its just for your own use you cant customize it.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wordpress.android&hl=en

And some others

http://apppresser.com/
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-publish-your-own-android-or-ios-wordpress-app/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to know whether its paid or free?

Comment: here is the pricing model, its free for the html app. But for a native app you will obviously have to pay for it.
http://www.wiziapp.com/pricing